# Как связать данные из DOM и JSON. Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette.js

```html
<ul class="link-area">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var SingleLink = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: '{{text}}',
    initialize: function  () {
        console.log('item');
    }
});

var ListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    childView: SingleLink,
    attach: function  () {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.find("li").each(function(index){
            new SingleLink({
                model: self.collection.get(index+1),
                el: $(this)
            });
        });
    },
    onAddChild: function(){
        console.log('child');
    }
});

var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var list = new List([
    {id: 1,text: 'item 1'},
    {id: 2,text: 'item 2'},
    {id: 3,text: 'item 3'}
]);

var view = (new ListView({
    collection: list,
    el: '.link-area'
}));

view.attach();
```

Когда добавляем еще один элемент, то рендер не срабатывает:

```
list.push({
    id: 4,
    text: 'item 4'
});
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или он сам всё свяжет и ничего трогать руками не надо?

Comment: Уточните вопрос или снимите с темы "требующий правки". Я понял проблему и смогу дать ответ.

Comment: @AriesUa Готово.

Comment: А вы уверены что вам нужен метод `attach`? Если да, то зачем? Может быть надо вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/5jgvc82m/